Need help figuring the steps to model this spiral
can anyone advise me on the operation steps to model this shape? It looks like you could get the original spiral by using the spin tool. Afterwards I am lost. Some kind of edge slide/bevel combined with a cut that changes the tris to quads?
Any help is greatly appreciated.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Hello do you need to do the animation or just modeling?

Here is something that looks close to what you show. Enable the addon called Add Curve: Extra Objects and create a Curve > Archemedian with these settings for example:

Then convert to mesh, begin to fill the faces, at one point just select an edge and press F as many times as needed:

You can scale down the center with the Proportional Editing option on:

Create an inner edge loop with CtrlR:

Dissolve the edge to get this:

Move up the edge loop:

You can extrude down:

Also you can bevel the crest:

